# SQL Group By Count Filtering Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, query-optimization

I'm wondering if group by count with filter works optimally, meaning that let's assume we have following query:

```
SELECT TenantId FROM SomeTable GROUP BY TenantId HAVING Count(*) >= 2
```

Are all elements counted for each group and then groups get filtered or there will be an optimization so as soon as some of the groups has more than 2 elements remaining elements will not be counted and group will be included in the final result?

And if there is no optimization would following query work better assuming that each group has a lot of rows:

```
SELECT [t1].TenantId FROM (
  SELECT [t0].TenantId FROM SomeTable AS [t0]
  GROUP BY [t0].TenantId) AS [t1]
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
  SELECT TOP(2) NULL AS [EMPTY]
  FROM SomeTable AS [t2]
  WHERE [t1].TenantId = [t2].TenantId
  ) AS [t3]
) >= 2
```

Comment: Why not run the 2 queries and compare the queries plans and execution times? We don't have access to your instance, nor do we know the definition of the table, the indexes it has, the size of the data, spread of the values, or anything. I would suspect that the former would be far faster as it results in 1 trip to the table, `SomeTable`, provided you have the right indexes, but *you* are in a infinitely better position to test this than we are.

Comment: The original question was does group by in this case count all rows for each group or it filters it as soon as finds more than 2 elements in it, how can I check that in execution plan?

Comment: The first question is *"I'm wondering if group by count with filter works optimally,"* not if the query considers all the rows.

Comment: Where did I say that it's you? :)

Comment: I *literally* quoted it in the comment... *"just need to read the whole question before downvoting"* There is no one else communicating with you in these comments. Your comment is in response to myself, so the remark is clearly aimed at myself. Up and down votes are anonymous, by design. The only way you would know if someone downvoter on a question is if they explicitly state they have, or you have access to the Stack Overflow database. If the comment wasn't aimed it me, then fine, but I would suggest you clarrify that, as it doesn't read that way. Thanks.

Comment: It's up to the downvoter to tell you why they downvoted though, if they want to (we can't enforce them to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To be able to do what you ask, you would need skip-scanning.** In other words, the server needs to read from each group just the necessary number of rows, then skip and seek to the next group.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not implement skip-scanning. This is partly to do with the fact that it is not actually as useful as you might imagine, because constantly skipping across the index is often less efficient than just scanning the whole thiing in the first place.

---

As you say, it can depend on the number of rows in each group. If, **and only if,** the size of the groups is very large relative to the `HAVING COUNT(*)` clause, then it **may** be worthwhile implementing a skip-scan yourself in order to get distinct values, [**as show by Paul White in this great article**](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/03/sql-performance/finding-distinct-values-quickly). It can be done with difficulty with a recursive CTE, but I'm not sure how it will optimize given you are grouping as well.

So I will show you the iterative table-variable solution, which should be just as fast. All credits to Paul White for this technique

```sql
DECLARE @Results TABLE (TenantId int NOT NULL, cnt int NOT NULL);
DECLARE @next int, @cnt int; 

SELECT TOP (1)
       @tenantId = TenantId, @cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY TenantId
    ORDER BY TenantId;

WHILE (@cnt > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT @Results (TenantId, cnt) VALUES (@TenantId, @cnt);
    
    SELECT TOP (1)
           @tenantId = TenantId, @cnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM SomeTable
        WHERE TenantId > @tenantId
        GROUP BY TenantId
        ORDER BY TenantId;
END;

SELECT TenantId
FROM @Results
WHERE cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation, and what about second query can it be in some case better than simple group by with having?

Comment: No, because it still needs to scan and group the whole table, it will be slower not faster. Although the only way to know for sure is to time it and to check the query plan

Answer (score 0):

Databases *could* move the filtering into the aggregation calculations.  However, I don't think that such an optimization is common.

I don't understand why you think that the second query would be better.  It is also aggregating the entire table -- and then using a much more complicated filtering clause. It is hard to imagine that it could be faster, but you can always check.

What *might* be faster is filtering *before* aggregation.  If you have large groups, a primary key, and the right indexes is:

```
SELECT TenantId
FROM SomeTable st
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SomeTable st2
              WHERE st2.TenantId = st.TenantId AND
                    st2.primary_key <> st.primary_key
             )
GROUP BY TenantId;
```